# Redirect to model creation if it doesn't exit

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When I login to django as a superuser, if an object of some model or the a field of the last object in that model doesn't exist or isn't set, how would I redirect to the creation of that model? And don't let me access the WebApp unless it's made?

I'm guessing there's a function to be run whenever a superuser logs in and check for an object or a field in the last object. I just don't know how to make this function and where to put it.

**EDIT: Really sorry, I didn't elaborate my question further. 

- I want to check for the existence of the object WHEN a superuser logs in to the webapp, not when they click on a model from the index. An object NEEDS to exist, that's why when it doesn't exist and a superuser logs in, they are to be taken to add form and not allowed to use the rest of the site until an object exists. So when someone logs in to the the Django Administration Site, I want to run a function that checks for the existence of that model and redirect or not, accordingly.**

Thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a signal to run a function after the point a user logs in

```py
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def superuser_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    if user.is_superuser:
        # Do stuff here
```

Comment: Thank you Mikey, that's just what I needed. I'll try it and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin, you can override `change_view` with something like this:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ... your admin declaration
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            MyModel.object.pk(pk=object_id)
            return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context):
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('admin:yourapp_yourmodel_add')
```

It's not sql optimized as `_changeform_view` will fectch your instance agin, but it's the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Julien, but I updated my question. I'm really sorry for not being clear at first. I basically want to run a function when ever a superuser logs in to the webapp.